# Past perfect can be used with 'for'?

Tags: tense

For example,

When i want to say

"He **suggested** the theory for 10 years. But he doesn't any more."

Can i use **had suggested** instead of **suggested** to indicate the action performed for the duration of time ?

Of course i understand that had pp is usually used to express the relative pass time being.
But this case is permitted too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the past perfect (if I understand you correctly). By using the past perfect you are saying that the act (suggesting) was done in the past and completed in the past.

Also, the rule is to always capitalize the personal pronoun ***I***. This is true wherever it is used in the sentence.